# How to access MySQL with Sequel Pro on Mac OSx?

Tags: macos, mysql, sequel-pro

So I am having an issue with trying to figure out how to connect to MySQL to create/edit a database using Sequel Pro on Mac OSX Lion.

I downloaded and installed MySQl from here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

I then added it to preferences pane and made sure the server was Running.

I downloaded and installed Sequel Pro from here:
http://www.sequelpro.com/download

When I run Sequel Pro it is asking me to use either Standard or Socket connection and is asking me for Host, Username and Password.

I think I want to use 127.0.0.1 as the host, but where/how do I set the username and password in MySQL as it did not ask me for those when I started it up!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after a couple of hours of searching, it turns out that the default username is `root` and the default password is just **left blank**! I am surprised at how hard it was to find this information. I guess if you come from a MySQL background then maybe you would know this but was not something easily figured out by me!

So for standard MySQL connection in Sequel Pro use:

```
    Host: 127.0.0.1
    Username: root
    Password: *(leave this blank)*
```

And you should now be able to create and edit a database now.

Comment: Here's the relevant part of the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html (it's in chapter *Installing and Upgrading MySQL*, section *Postinstallation Setup and Testing*)